# Android notification large icon, is there a way to remove the smaller icon on the bottom right?

Tags: android, notifications, status

I have a notification that displays a largeicon.

Is there any way to remove the smaller icon from honeycomb and above devices from this view?

Obviously still keeping the small icon for the top status bar

[image]

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)


            // Set required fields, including the small icon, the
            // notification title, and text.
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status_new)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)


            // All fields below this line are optional.

            // Use a default priority (recognized on devices running Android
            // 4.1 or later)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            // Provide a large icon, shown with the notification in the
            // notification drawer on devices running Android 3.0 or later.
            .setLargeIcon(picture)

            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            notiIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            );


    builder = getNotiSettings(builder);
    notify(context, builder.build());
```

Comment: `Big views were introduced in Android 4.1, and they're not supported on older devices.` http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 14):

Add this code after you build the notification.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int smallIconViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());

        if (smallIconViewId != 0) {
            if (notif.contentIntent != null)
                notif.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);

            if (notif.headsUpContentView != null)
                notif.headsUpContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);

            if (notif.bigContentView != null)
                notif.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

where "notif" is your built notification,

Comment: thanks a lot , it works for me and i do not check the SDK_INT ,just getting smallIconViewId  and set view as invisible works good on api lower than 21 too

Comment: Did you mean if (notif.contentView != null) instead of notif.contentIntent?

Comment: No i did not, this is the intent to execute when the expanded status entry is clicked

Comment: What's the relationship between notif.contentIntent and notif.contentView?

Comment: Please change `if (notif.contentIntent != null)` to `if (notif.contentView != null)`

Comment: `Notification.contentView.setImageViewResource()` works, but `contentView` is deprecated. But using `NotificationCompat.Builder.getContentView().setImageViewResource()` (before or after `NotificationCompat.Builder.build()` or `NotificationManager.notify()`) does not work

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way:
Use your custom layout

Your question is probable a duplicate of [NotificationCompat 4.1 SetSmallIcon and SetLargeIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847297/notificationcompat-4-1-setsmallicon-and-setlargeicon)

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate.
No, there is other way: not use "setLargeIcon".

Answer (score -1):

Use only setSmallIcon for Your icon. It will be also used for largeIcon if second wasn't specified (just make sure it is big enough to fit both).

Make sure that it looks good on pre-lolipop, lolipop and above. For example here I do set application icon only for pre-lolipop devices, where lolipop and above are getting different smallIcon and same largeIcon as smallIcon.

```
int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notificationBuilder
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setLargeIcon(appIconDrawable)
} else {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(appIconDrawable);
}
```