# NotificationCompat android - how to show only Large icon without small

Tags: android, notifications

When I add notification:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.plus)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setAutoCancel(true) 
.setContentText(text)
.setSound(RingtoneManager .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
.setLargeIcon(bm);
```

I see large icon and small in it: [image]

How can I set only large Icon, without small.
If use only setLargeIcon, I don't see notification at all, just sound alert.

Comment: i want to this type of notification like "E" image and than circle in corner of E image please help i cannot get.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Small icon is mandatory.
If you don't set a large one you'll get your small icon bigger in the middle of the circle with the color of your choice (setColor).

If i were you i'd put that blank E on a transparent background for smallicon, and set a red color for the circle.

Answer (score 9):

get the small icon id and then try to hide it

```
int smallIconId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());
if (smallIconId != 0) { 
    if (notification.contentView!=null)
        notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

try looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914198/5182546) it will help too

i test the code on api 18,23 (samsung j1,galaxy S6) work fine

Comment: notice : small icon is required one that means you should set value for that , but you can try the code above to hide small icon ,...

Comment: Or just set a transparent one and don't make crazy asumptions about the icon id not changing name

Comment: i did not try to transparent the small icon but working with id was good for me ;) but finally it is your way if you say so

Comment: Setting a transparent icon doesn't work as you don't see you icon in the status bar then. Instead you should create a custom content view and pass it to the builder with setContentView

Comment: Above code helped to hide the small icon when user pull the notification. But in lint shows  "notification.contentView" is deprecated, any alternative for this to remove warning?

Comment: @ashokreddy I use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` and I don't worry about it unless I need ro raise the API levels.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answer you can also hide the expended view too :

```
int smallIconId = AnghamiApp.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());
            if (smallIconId != 0) {
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom notification and then show whatever you want in the large notification area.
See and example here [TutorialsFace: Build all types of Notifications in Android](http://tutorialsface.blogspot.co.il/2014/07/build-all-types-of-notifications-in.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Hii There")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smallicon))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(123, notification);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hii Everyone this is my first answer sorry i give late answer..Please Try this answer you get title Msg and large icon  ignore class things you can implement it any class