# Can I disable notification badge on android and small notification icon?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, badge, android-8.1-oreo

I read that is possible to use a transparent color to "hide" the smallIcon but there's a gap between icons.

Also I need to disable the notification badge; I just need the sound and the notification on the lock-screen(visibility =1) and the notification on the top notification bar.

Comment: So many touchy people. So many animosity. Instead of putting negatives explain what I'm doing wrong so I can learn; or I will keep making the same mistake over and over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable Notification badge you can use [setShowBadge(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setShowBadge(boolean)) on your `NotificationChannel` object.

Checkout more [Modify a Notification Badge](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges).

The other part of i.e removing small icon . AFAIK its not possible since its a mandatory in place of large icon. Although I am not completely sure about it .
As a work around you can use a small icon with transparent background.

Comment: I have a transparent icon now but if the user have another small icons from anothers apps it shows a missing icon, a gap in the notification bar. Also, now, and thanks to you, I just changed my code to setShowBadge(false) but I will know if it worked tomorrow when I get a phone with true Android Oreo since mine have Android Oreo Go that for some reason doesn't show any badges.

Comment: Well I am not sure what gap you are taking about . 0adding a image with question might helpful . I have found a [`Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887078/notificationcompat-android-how-to-show-only-large-icon-without-small) discussing the same . Please have a look .

Comment: I mean I get icon icon icon empty space icon icon.... .The other icons are from another Apps