# Get rid of little notification in notification

Tags: android, notifications

Anyone know how to get rid of the little notification icons that seems to pop up in the notification? It's the icons circled in red. Is this an inbuilt thing that is automatically done? Those numbers are the icons that appear in the notification, but I don't want them in the dropped down notifications.

[EDIT]
Basically I have 150 icons in the res folder and depending on what the temperature is, the corresponding icon will be used for the notification. So as one example below, the temperature is 19.8 I round either up or down to get the icon that I use for the notification. So 20 was used in example below. But the notification has that icon in the notification dropdown. I would prefer that it wasn't there.

```
            // Build the Notification
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                .setTicker(tickerText)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLargeIcon(drawableToBitmap(iconDrawable))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
                .setOngoing(true);
```

[image: Notification KitKat]

[image: Notification Lollipop]

[image: Secondary Icon]

This last picture has the arrow pointed to it, that is what I mean by the "secondary icon" that I want removed.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setNumber%28int%29

Comment: Sorry @CommonsWare but that is not a number, that is an icon that is circled, I have 150 numbered icons that gets selected from the res folder depending on the temperature on the weather staions. It is technically an icon. so setNumber() is not what I'm looking for but I learnt something new with that.

Comment: Does this circled number only appear only on lollipop devices ? If so, you are probably calling `setNumber()` somewhere.

Comment: It's for both kitkat and lollipop. I'm not calling setNumber() anywhere.

Comment: In your top screenshot, how do you set the number 20 in the red circle ? Post the code you use to create the notification.

Comment: The number is an icon that gets selected from the res folder, so depending on what the temperature is, will depend in the icon. So if the temperature is 15.2 then I round it up/down and select that icon and use that for the setSmallIcon(). I have added the notification builder above.

Comment: I suppose you could use an entirely transparent icon on lollipop devices, so it doesen't show up. But that would also remove the icon in the notification bar though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using `.setNumber(int)`for the '20' at the first picture, but you could do it if not.

Otherwise you can't with the newer versions disable the small icon from your notifications.

[Jerzyna's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280530/3329810).

But even if so, you can use it to show the temperature for example on the notification bar (icon of 20°C) and by dropping down the notification bar you can show with `.setLargeIcon(Bitmap)` your App-Icon.

Otherwise the other solution is to accept the simple `.setSmallIcon(Icon)` with the border on the bigger notification icon and remove the `.setLargeIcon(Bitmap)`.

But in your situation I would try to use 2 different icons, as I said before, for a better look before you start to create any notification contents.